# Python Request to send a file with a specific part

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to send a file via the request library but the receiver requires a part with a designated name (receivers terminology).  I have something like this... so far:

```
filePath = os.path.join( GetDownloadFolder(), fileName )
files    = {'upload': open( str( filePath ),'rb')}    
response = requests.post( url, headers=header, files=files, verify=False )
```

GetDownloadFolder() simply gets the location where the file is.  Header contains the account info and content type.  The code above talks to the server and no longer complains that the file cannot be found.  I get an error back from the server that a part with a specific name must exist.  I tried using the data=values parameters with:

```
values      = {'upload': ''}
```

That unfortunately didn't solve the issue.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the exact error message you are receiving?

Comment: (off-topic) Please have a look at [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: @Windmill - It says that I'm missing a named part and it gives the name.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my... After a bit of debugging I figured it out.  The receiver had the wrong error.  I had set the content type myself as Content-Type: multipart/form-data.

When I sent file I got back an error stating that I'm missing a named part.  I removed the setting of the content type and requests filled out the header like this instead.

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=3645c8b2b8f74e1a8db8a85c54225964

At that point... the received accepted the data.  So the boundary is important.  Probably is the size of the content being received or some such detail.